# How to synchronise multiple writer on redis?

Tags: redis, synchronization

I have multiple writers overwriting the same key in redis. How do I guarantee that only the chosen one write last?

Can I perform write synchronisation in Redis withour synchronise the writers first?

---

Background:
In my system a unique dispatcher send works to do to various workers. Each worker then write the result in Redis overwrite the same key. I need to be sure that only the last worker that receive work from the dispatcher writes in Redis.

Comment: Are you sure you want the last one who is given work or the last one to complete it?

Comment: @TheRealBill Totally sure: the last one who has been given work will have the most up to date data. Actually is 'the last data sent from the dispatcher'.

Answer (score 4):

Use an ordered set (**ZSET**): add your entry with a score equal to the unix timestamp, then delete all but the top rank.

A Redis [Ordered set](https://redis.io/topics/data-types) is a set, where each entry also has a **score**. The set is ordered according to the score, and the position of an element in the ordered set is called **Rank.**

In order:

1. Remove all the entries with score equal or less then the one you are adding([zremrangebyscore](https://redis.io/commands/zrevrangebyscore)). Since you are adding to a set, in case your value is duplicate your new entry would be ignored, you want instead to keep the entry with highest rank.
2. Add your value to the zset ([zadd](https://redis.io/commands/zadd))
3. delete by rank all the entries but the one with HIGHEST rank ([zremrangebyrank](https://redis.io/commands/zremrangebyrank))
4. You should do it inside a transaction ([pipeline](https://redis.io/topics/pipelining))

Example in python:

```
# timestamp contains the time when the dispatcher sent a message to this worker
key = "key_zset:%s"%id
pipeline = self._redis_connection.db.pipeline(transaction=True)
pipeline.zremrangebyscore(key, 0, t)  # Avoid duplicate Scores and identical data
pipeline.zadd(key, t, "value")
pipeline.zremrangebyrank(key, 0, -2)
pipeline.execute(raise_on_error=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would use [redlock](https://redis.io/topics/distlock).

Before you write to that key, you acquire the lock for it, then update it and then release the lock.

I use Node.js so it would look something like this, not actually correct code but you get the idea.

```
Promise.all(startPromises)
        .bind(this)
        .then(acquireLock)
        .then(withLock)
        .then(releaseLock)
        .catch(handleErr)


function acquireLock(key) {
    return redis.rl.lock(`locks:${key}`, 3000)
}

function withLock(lock) {
    this.lock = lock
    // do stuff here after get the lock
}

function releaseLock() {
    this.lock.unlock()
}
```

Comment: That is an alternative to the transaction. It would still leave in redis the data from the last writer and not the data of a specific writer (based on timestamp). Is in any way redlock more performant than a pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

You can use redis pipeline with [Transaction](https://redis.io/topics/transactions).

Redis is single threaded server. Server will execute commands syncronously. When Pipeline with transaction is used, server will execute all commands in pipeline atomically.

> **Transactions**
>
> > MULTI, EXEC, DISCARD and WATCH are the foundation of transactions in Redis. They allow the execution of a group of commands in a single step, with two important guarantees:
> >     All the commands in a transaction are serialized and executed sequentially. It can never happen that a request issued by another client is served in the middle of the execution of a Redis transaction. This guarantees that the commands are executed as a single isolated operation.

A simple example in python

```
with redis_client.pipeline(transaction=True) as pipe:
    val = int(pipe.get("mykey"))
    val = val*val%10
    pipe.set("mykey",val)
    pipe.execute()
```

Comment: This guarantee that no 2 writer will write at the same time, however does not guarantee that a _specific_ writer will write last, and that other writers will not overwrite the data.

Comment: I find it ok if one requires server side synchronization. If one requires client side synchronization in distributed environment, [distlock](https://redis.io/topics/distlock) would be best option.